# Regular Expressions Replace with Placeholders

Tags: c#, regex

I have a String:

```
AAA foobarfoobarfoobar foo baar bar foo BBB and so on
```

After the Replace it should looke like:

```
AAA foobarfoobarfoobar foo baar bar foo
```

basically the BBB and everything behind it shall be stripped. so my first thought was an expression like:

```
BBB.*
```

Which actually does the Job. But i only want this to work, if BBB stands behind an AAA, so that

```
BBB bbb AAA aaa BBB ccc
```

whill be replaced to

```
BBB bbb AAA aaa
```

the first BBB is staying because there is no AAA in front of it.

my thought was an expression like

```
AAA.*?BBB.*
```

this would match the correct parts i think, but it will also kill the whole thing. So I know there are placeholders or something, but couldnt find out how to use them correctly. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try someting like this

```
(?<=AAA.*?)BBB.*
```

`(?<=AAA.*)` is a look behind assertion, .net is able to handle them without length restriction, so it should be working for you.

The other solution would be

```
(AAA.*?)BBB.*
```

and replace with the content from the capturing group 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=AAA.*?)BBB.*$
```

which will ensure that `AAA` will precede `BBB`. Quick test:

```
PS> 'BBB bbb AAA aaa BBB ccc' -replace 'AAA.*?BBB.*$'
BBB bbb
PS> 'BBB bbb AAA aaa BBB ccc' -replace '(?<=AAA.*)BBB.*$'
BBB bbb AAA aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how far c# implements those features, but you can use either

positive look-behind to find a match and don't replace it
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

or you can store the (AAA.*) part and insert it in the replacement